# Show errors or console file lua in editor php

Tags: php, lua, console

I use PHP for edit code LUA, change and save file. I can execute the file, but I can not use show if I have error, as console.

example:

my code lua:

```
print "hello"
```

and code php:

```
  <?php

        $output = passthru("sudo /usr/local/bin/lua /var/www/test.lua");

        //show output 
        echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

    ?>
```

this work, but I can show errors (console), if code has.

i think use the code io.stdin or io.stdout in lua

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php#101148

When Lua fails and responds with an error, `passthrough` can't capture the result, even though I get the `STDERR` text without any problems, you may, as suggested in the comment, try piping the Lua result to `tee` program.

```
$output = passthru("sudo /usr/local/bin/lua /var/www/test.lua | tee");
```